# What could cause PSExec to only work remotely?

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am trying to update some legacy software so that it works on a new computer. The software connects to an AS400 with runs a `.bat`file on the local machine.

The command:

```
psexec \\localhost -i c:\path\to\file.bat s3
```

works like a champ when executed from the command line on the local machine, but when fired from the AS400, nothing happens. No errors. No anything.

Any ideas?

**update** The computer is a Windows 7 machine.

**update 2 - batch file contents**

```
FTP -s:C:\scls\PGINPC3I.FTP i.p.a.d.d.r.e.s.s
C:\scls\NGINPC3 S3
FTP -s:C:\scls\PGINPC3O.FTP i.p.a.d.d.r.e.s.s
```

Comment: Is it the first time PSExec has been run on the AS400?

Comment: @MattWilliamson I don't have physical access to the AS400, but I don't think so. What are your recommendations though - at this point I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: I'm confused...are you trying to run `PSEXEC.EXE` on the AS400? If so, that's not going to work.

Comment: @aphoria No - the AS400 is sending a command to the windows 7 PC telling it to run PSExec

Comment: Can you run any other executable on the Windows 7 PC via this method?

Comment: I assume you're using `RUNRMTCMD` from the AS400 to run the program on the Windows 7 PC. If so, why use `PSEXEC`? Why not just runt the `.bat` file?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your version of `PSExec` is recent. If you haven't ran PSExec on the remote machine physically and accepted the license agreement, you'll get this kind of behavior. There is an undocumented switch for `PSExec` to alleviate this kind of issue. it's `/accepteula` just add that in your call to `PSExec` and see what happens.

Exactly like this with the forward slash:

```
psexec \\localhost -i /accepteula c:\path\to\file.bat s3
```

**EDIT**

The -c switch:

```
 -c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
            execution. If you omit this option the application
            must be in the system path on the remote system.
```

Comment: Ah, I have accepted the EULA. I was getting a 4500 error on the AS400 before accepting. Now that I have accepted it, I get no errors, it just refuses to work.

Comment: What is in the batch file? Have you tried the -c switch?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a c switch - but I just added the contents of the batch file to my question. Does that help?

Comment: where should I put the -c in my bat file?

Comment: -c is a switch for psexec. So you put it in the call to psexec. `psexec \\localhost -i -c "c:\path\to\file.bat s3"`

Comment: I'd look into [RUNRMTCMD](http://search400.techtarget.com/answer/Activate-a-PC-program-from-the-AS-400) I don't think PSExec will work in this scenario.